# Best practices for setting up a docker container for data processing project on ECS

Tags: python, shell, docker, amazon-ecs

I am currently doing some experimentation with AWS Elastic Container Service in the context of creating a data processing pipeline and I had a few questions regarding the specifics of how best to set up the docker container/ecs task definitions.

The general goal of the project is to create a system that allows users to add data files to an S3 bucket to trigger an ECS task using S3 events and Lambda, then return the outputs to another S3 bucket.

So far I've been able to figure out the S3 triggers and the basics of Lambda, but I am a bit more confused on how to properly set up the docker container and task definition so that it automatically processes the data using a set of python scripts. I believe that creating a docker container that runs a shell script that copies the necessary files and calls the python code makes sense, but I was confused on how to run the docker container with a bind mounted volume from an ECS task, and also whether or not this process makes sense. Currently, when I am testing the system on a single EC2, I am running my docker container using:

```
docker run -b $ (pwd)/data:/home/ec2-user/docker_test/data docker_test
```

I'm still relatively new to the AWS tools, so please let me know if I can clarify any of my points/questions and thank you in advance!

Comment: Not a bad idea! Can you clarify the need doing a volume mount? I see that you mentioned the data to be in an S3 bucket.

Comment: From what I've read, I thought I needed to mount a volume to process my data in the docker container. If this is not the case how is this kind of thing usually done?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that that is what you wanted to do. The other alternative is fetching the objects if you're only processing the Objects in the UpdateEvent. I guess your intent is to process the entirety of the data in the bucket. You can use `s3fs-fuse` for this.

Comment: To be a little more specific, I'm expecting users to drop in a .zip file containing their data into an s3 bucket. Each zip will be it's own task and will be processed separately. Does using a mounted volume make sense for this?

Comment: I don't think so. There is a similar architectural pattern you can start with that exercise this same use case that the AWS team has documented https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/. The only thing that may change in your implementation could be implementing the task in a language other than shell.

Comment: Basically, You want an ecs task which will run on every put event in s3 -> download the file -> process it using your custom python login -> upload the data back to some s3 bucket and stop. Do let me know if I am missing out something.

Comment: Yes exactly. I already have the python processing code done, as well as the dockerfile.